# Difference between VS 2022 Professional Retail and the VS 2022 Professional Subscription version

Tags: visual-studio

Our small organization is considering buying Visual Studio 2022 professional. We are not able to use the Community version due to our revenues exceeds the 1 million cap.

We noticed that we could buy the VS 2022 professional from Microsoft Store, and its price is considerably lower than the VS 2022 professional Subscription.

Would anyone know if there is a major difference between the VS 2022 professional, bought from the Store, and the Subscription one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Azure or planning to use it, the professional subscription may add value.

If you are using AWS/GCP very little value. A professional subscription will provide 3 months of Pluralsight access and some other partners' trial versions etc.

I think the visual studio is facing competition with Jetbrain's RIder. A lot of devs feel it is better than Visual Studio. However, from a cost perspective, it is not economical either.

Usually, companies can claim these reoccurring costs on tax.

Comment: Thank you.

We just got a subscription for Jetbrain Rider. In our team there is only one developer doing .NET so I feel that is appropriate. Once the 1 year subscription is over, we will re-evaluate and decide if we keep Rider of go with Visual Studio.